# Why PHP in CLI need a few seconds to start?

Tags: php, macos

I got problem. My PHP 5.5.8 need a few seconds to start.

If in terminal run this command `php -v`, it will print version only a few seconds later (about 13). But second run prints it immediately. If i wait a little bit all the same.

What to do?

```
$ time php -v
PHP 5.5.8 (cli) (built: Jan 12 2014 18:50:29) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

real    0m13.375s
user    0m0.029s
sys 0m0.024s
```

Comment: Are you using php-imap for similar? Did you configure any imap-specific values in your php.ini configuration that might cause the slowdown? Or is there an `auto_prepend_file` configuration that's using imap when it's available?

Comment: How to check it? I'm just install php via php-osx.liip.ch

Comment: imap is enabled. 
IMAP c-Client Version 2007f

Comment: auto_prepend_file: no value

Comment: Try uninstalling php-imap.

Comment: Is there are a simple way to disable imap? Or i need to reconfigure php and compile it?

Comment: You might check [this answer for similar issue][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510665/php-cli-has-a-few-seconds-delay/29510666#29510666