# PHP CLI has a few seconds delay

Tags: php, centos, command-line-interface, delay

When I run PHP in the CLI mode (PHP 5.6.6 under CentOS 6.5 running as VM using VirtualBox) it has a few seconds of delay even if I only check version and there is php.ini file disabled:

```
time php -n -v
PHP 5.6.6 (cli) (built: Apr  2 2015 14:18:24) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

real    0m5.066s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is related to DNS call PHP is doing. See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/586141/php-cli-with-imap-5-second-startup-delay) and [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65632).

The solution is to add hostname

```
[root@dev-machine ~]# hostname
dev-machine.com
```

to /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 dev-machine.com
```

Result:

```
time php -n -v
PHP 5.6.6 (cli) (built: Apr  2 2015 14:18:24) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.004s
```